# Select query executing twice

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing a simple page to retrieve "PO Numbers" that belong to the logged-in user. That portion is working fine with the exception of the query returning 2 complete sets of records. I have checked for page refresh issues, as mentioned in other posts I've read, but none have been found.

poTable.php

```
    <table class="table" style="width: 100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">PO#</th>
                <th scope="col">Job#</th>
                <th scope="col">Job Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Salesperson</th>
                <th scope="col">Vendor</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php include 'usersPOs.php'?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

usersPOs.php

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'acs-jobs-pos');

$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$userPrivs = $_SESSION['admin'];

if ($userPrivs == 0) {  // User IS NOT an admin
    // Get ALL main table records that belong to the logged-in user
    $sqlmain = "SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN users ON main.userID = '" . $userID . "'";
    //debug_print_backtrace(); 
    $resultmain = mysqli_query($db,$sqlmain);
    while($rowmain = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultmain))  
    {  
?>  
            <tr>  
<?php
        $PONumb = $rowmain["PONumb"];
        $jobNumber = $rowmain["jobNumber"];
        $jobName = $rowmain["jobName"];
        $salespersonID = $rowmain["salespersonID"];
        $vendorID = $rowmain["vendorID"];
        $timestamp = $rowmain["timestamp"];
?>

                <td><?php echo $PONumb ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $jobNumber ?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $jobName ?></td>

<?php
        $sqlsp = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '" . $salespersonID . "'";
        $resultsp = mysqli_query($db,$sqlsp);   
        $rowsp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsp);

        if ($rowsp["lastname"] == '' && $rowsp["firstname"] == '') {
?>
                <td></td>
<?php
        } else {
?>
                <td><?php echo $rowsp["lastname"] . ', ' . $rowsp["firstname"] ?></td>
<?php
        }

        $sqlvendor = "SELECT * FROM vendor 
                        WHERE vendorID = '" . $vendorID . "'";
        $resultvendor = mysqli_query($db,$sqlvendor);   
        $rowvendor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultvendor);
?>
            <td><?php echo $rowvendor["vendorname"] ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $timestamp ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php  
    }  
    mysqli_close($db);      
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your while loop is not executing more than once?

Comment: I sound stupid for asking but, is there an easy way to test for that condition? That's exactly what it appears to be doing.

Comment: I don't know your data. But if I knew the first record back is what i wanted I would not have a while. Just an if to check for data. You could put a break; at the end of the while to kill it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: You might want to check this JOIN `SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN users ON main.userID = '" . $userID . "'`

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll do some homework.

Comment: RiggsFolly, you nailed it! I ran it in phpMyAdmin and yep, it returned 2 sets. What am I doing wrong, if you don't mind giving me a bit of education?

Comment: SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN users ON users.userID = '" . $userID . "' ... I need to study up on join queries I guess.

Comment: The code says you want to get ALL main records for the user. Why is it wrong to return multiple records if that's what there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code could be hugely simplified by use of joins. I'd also recommend using PDO for your database access; it's less verbose and makes prepared statements easier (and those are not optional in any environment.) Only relevant columns are selected from the database. A heredoc block is also used to simplify output.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=acs-jobs-pos', 'root', '');

$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$userPrivs = $_SESSION['admin'];

if ($userPrivs == 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT m.PONumb, m.jobNumber, m.jobName, m.salespersonID, m.vendorID, m.timestamp,
        u.lastname, u.firstname, v.vendorname
        FROM main m
        LEFT JOIN users u ON (m.salespersonID = u.userID)
        LEFT JOIN vendors v ON (m.vendorID = v.vendorID)
        WHERE m.userID = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$userID]);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo <<< HTML
<tr>
    <td>$row[PONumb]</td>  
    <td>$row[jobNumber]</td>  
    <td>$row[jobName]</td>
    <td>$row[lastname], $row[firstname]</td>
    <td>$row[vendorname]</td>
    <td>$row[timestamp]</td>
</tr>
HTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you miken32. I have to say, I have always been blown away by people that are good at their craft! I have a lot of learning/reading to do. Thank you so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

follow sql error
"SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN users ON main.userID = '" . $userID . "'";

you can not use join as this, something like 
"SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN users ON main.userID = users.ID where users.ID='" . $userID . "'";